# correction of a signal played with speakers

Tags: signals, fft

I have 8 speakers, I created a signal and play it while recording it, so i have 8 arrays, I calculated the phase and the amplitudes of the signals and i want now to correct them all to make them being equal, i heard abour a way using the fft/ifft.

i tried to devide the arrays i ve record by a signal i created with the amplitudes and phases i ve calculated earlier but the phase are not corrected and i don t know why.

i have a list with my amplitudes and phases:

amplitude = [A1,A2,...]
phase = [p1p2,...]

i created a signal with :

correction = [amplitude[n]*np.exp(1j*phase[n]n*t) for n in range(numbers of speakers=8)] and t is the time of records

and i devide my recording arrays by it :

corrected = [np.fft.fft(rec[n])/correction[n] for n in range (8)]
corrected_time = [np.fft.ifft(corrected[n]) for n in range(8)]

and it correct my amplitudes but the phases steal wrong